# Hyperledger Fabric CA: What is the purpose of registering a user when enroll can be used to do the same?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Reading fabric-ca [docs](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html) its not clear what is the purpose of `fabric-ca-client register` when it seems that `fabric-ca-client enroll` can be used to accomplish everything in the realm of `fabric-ca-client register`. Indeed the cert is issued only when `fabric-ca-client enroll` is run. Also for the bootstrap identity there is no `fabric-ca-client register` step in the docs.

Can someone provide an example illustrating what it is that `register` does which `enroll` cannot do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

REGISTER is used to make the CA aware of a new user that CAN be enrolled. You may set various options for the user (see `fabric-ca-client register --help`). Once you have registered the user, then the CA server will accept an enrolment API request for that user (given that the enrolment secret matches). This enrolment request includes the a CSR generated by the user. If the CA server accepts this enrolment request, it will return a signed x509 certificate. This will allow the user to communicate with the fabric network (where applicable).

> Can someone provide an example illustrating what it is that register
>   does which enroll cannot do?

To make this more clear:

- `ENROLL` REQUIRES that a user already be registered.
- `REGISTER` DOES NOT provide a signed x509 certficate.

Comment: also check https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io for more details

Comment: Other than the bootstrap admin user (and optionally other bootstrap users defined in config) all users are required to be registered first. In fact even the bootstrap users are registered on first start up.

Comment: Also, the default admin bootstrap user should only be used for CA administration (registering,revoking additional users, exc). Your application that requires enrollment credentials should be seperate users registered will less permissions granted on the CA.

Comment: @morpheus please accept this answer for future users (unless you feel it's wrong) thanks